# Center of matrices over a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, field-theory

I'm trying to find the center of $\mathbb{M}_n(K)$ with $K$ a field. I know what the center would be if $K$ was a ring, but I think this isn't the same for a field $K$. In particular I'm trying to find $Z(\mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{F}_2))$.

Comment: Every field is a ring.

Comment: @Travis Well, a very near match to the center of a general linear group, but of course the ring of matrices includes many more elements than invertible matrices, and the final answer is different by an element (the zero matrix).   Nevertheless, there is an exact duplicate and I've included it. If you see more, please use this one instead.

Comment: @rschwieb Oops, you're right, of course! Alas, the "The question already has an answer here: ..." is now misleading.